# What is dangling logic?

Tags: vhdl

When compiling my VHDL design in Altera Quartos II I get this notification in the connectivity report for a couple of my nets (signals). What does *dangling logic* mean exactly?

> Connected to dangling logic. Logic that only feeds a dangling port will be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A part of your design is not used and can(from the tool's point of view) be removed  without changing the output. I the signals could be unconnected or unused at test bench level

Comment: Is it just the tools way to tell me that I didn't connect the net to anything?

Comment: Yes ... or more specifically you didn't connect it to anything that is ultimately connected to an output.

Comment: I understand the principle and can review the report to know that given warning can be safely ignored. However, some of these warnings are result of IPs I instantiated. As an example PLL IP has many outputs I do not need. Is there a clean way to explicitly unconnected to avoid extra warnings?